# Include CSS Content page in Masterpage ASP.NET

Tags: css, asp.net, master-pages

why i cannot adding css Content Page in Master Page Asp.Net.
i cannot change..

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

then i use css

```
#name {
width:300px;
height: 300px;
}
```

but he did not change.
anyone can help me resolve this?

Comment: Right-click the textbox in your browser and inspect element (chrome), you will see the ID is no longer "name". It changes when the page renders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default server object ID's aren't rendered exactly the same.  You should either use a class instead or set `clientidmode` to `static` for the textbox.

If you view the source on the rendered page and look for that textbox, you'll find the ID is probably a few names separated by an underscore.

Here is the same markup with a static client id.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static"></asp:TextBox>
```

Please note that you shouldn't do this for any control that you plan to repeat on a page.

In that case you should use a class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this CSS  using Class
because When Server control render in page then Their ID is Unique  that generate by IIS foloowd by contant page Holder Name

means

```
<asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
this will genrate 
<input id="ContantPlaceholderName_name" name="ContantPlaceholderName_name"/>
```

so use class name is better option

Comment: thank you for having contributed. I really appreciate. Smeegs has helped me.

Comment: yes, that's also good solution but you have to remember their is no duplicate id on page